# Hide/Show Columns in MS Access Query using a Checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access 2016 and building a form to run a query that enables users to only extract columns that they need. I am planning on doing this with a checkbox for every column. How can I do this? I have tried the following but it does not work. It gives me a Compile Error: Method or data member not found.

```
Private Sub chk1_AfterUpdate()
  Me.column4.Visible = Nz(Me.chk1 = True, False)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
  Me.column4.Visible = Nz(Me.chk1 = True, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.columnhidden

Answer (score 1):

You can hide a control but not a field. So try, where TextBox4 is bound to your column4:

```vb
Private Sub chk1_AfterUpdate()
    Me!TextBox4.Visible = Nz(Me!chk1.Value, False)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me!TextBox4.Visible = Nz(Me!chk1.Value, False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub Check20_Click()
         If Me.Check20.Value = -1 Then
         Me.ID.Visible = False
         Else
         Me.ID.Visible = True
         End If
   End Sub
```

## i will advise you to be careful placing any code under the form_current event, because it might be tricky to implement, this approach

Comment: Thank you but this code still gives me the same error: Method or data member not found